# How to combine string in one column based on grouping

Tags: sql

I have a table has data like this
[image: Table 1]

And want to combine the job which has same template in one column, like this
[image: Final Table]

I try to use FOR XML PATH

select t.JBTemplate,
  Stuff(
  (SELECT N', ' + Contract FROM Table1 FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
  .value('text()[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dMD1.png)','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'') Job
  from  Table1 t
  group by t.JBTemplate, Contract

However, it combine all job for each template.

[image: Current query result]

Comment: There is a lot of similar questions you could find on SO and also you can use [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thank,I have searched before post, but could not find the similars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#my_job_template') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE #my_job_template
END;


CREATE TABLE #my_job_template (JCCO INT NOT NULL, [Contract] nvarchar(max) NULL, [JBTemplate] nvarchar(max) NULL);

INSERT INTO #my_job_template(JCCO, [JBTemplate], [Contract])
       VALUES (17, 'Ascend AL',  '601226.17')
             ,(17, '1192-10803', '601236.17')
             ,(17, 'P66_4Sites', '600948.17')
             ,(17, 'P66_4Sites', '601219.17')
             ,(17, 'P66_4Sites', '601234.17')

--select * from #my_job_template

SELECT      [JCCO]
            , [JBTemplate]
            ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST([Contract] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) [text()]
            FROM #my_job_template 
            WHERE [JBTemplate] = t.[JBTemplate]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') [Contract] 
            FROM #my_job_template t
            GROUP BY [JBTemplate] , [JCCO]
```